# Difference in the array type using numpy and cupy

Tags: python-3.x, chainer, cupy

I am using chainer library for my model and facing the below issue: 
Say I have a file of test data having 3 features and a label (last column) with them. It is imported in the form of a list.
e.g.

```
test_set = [[1,0,9,1],[7,0,8,1],[7,0,2,0],[8,0,1,0]]
```

Then I take the labels by converting the data into a numpy array and taking the labels column,
which I later convert into a list for comparison with the predicted labels say y_pred = [1,1,1,0]. i.e.

```
import numpy as np
y_true_np = list(np.array(test_set)[:,3])
print(y_true_np)
[1, 1, 0, 0]
```

My concern is when I run my model in GPU, it uses Cuda.cupy instead of numpy as I am using chainer library, and when I fetch the true labels I receive them as:

There by in cupy:

```
import cupy as cp
y_true_cp = list(cp.array(test_set)[:,3]) Or
y_true_cp = list(cuda.cp.array(test_set)[:,3])
```

Both returns a list of array:

```
y_true_cp: [array(1), array(1), array(0), array(0)]
```

As a workaround, I am using numpy in that specific place. Am I doing something wrong while using cupy, due to which I am not getting the values correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While NumPy converts 0-dimensional arrays to scalars, CuPy does not.
https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/difference.html#zero-dimensional-array

In the result `[array(1), array(1), array(0), array(0)]`, each data of arrays is on GPU.  I'd use `cupy.asnumpy` if an efficient CPU array is needed.

`y_true_cp = list(cp.asnumpy(cp.array(test_set)[:,3]))`

Answer (score 1):

There is no necessity to go through numpy.

Input

```
import cupy as cp

test_set = [[1,0,9,1],[7,0,8,1],[7,0,2,0],[8,0,1,0]]
test_set = cp.array(test_set)

x_true = test_set[:, :3]
y_true = test_set[:, 3]
print("x_true:\n".format(x_true))
print("y_true:\n".format(y_true))
```

Output

```
x_true:
[[1 0 9]
 [7 0 8]
 [7 0 2]
 [8 0 1]]
y_true:
[1 1 0 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, it seems the behavior when you wrap by `list` is different

```
import numpy as np
import cupy as cp

print(list(np.arange(3))  # --> [0, 1, 2]
print(list(cp.arange(3))  # --> [array(0), array(1), array(2)]
```

However in your case, I think you can just use `numpy` array or `cupy` array without converting `list`.

```
y_true = test_set[:, 3]  # it should work for both numpy & cupy
y_true_np = cuda.to_cpu(y_true)  # If you want to convert the array to numpy
```